# zend json object

Tags: json, zend-framework

Having this code:

(...)

```
<?php foreach($this->albums as $album) : 
$jsonalbum = Zend_Json::encode($album);
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($album->tstamp);?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($album->title);?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($album->place);?></td>
    <td class="link" onclick="popup(<?php echo $jsonalbum; ?>)">>></td>
    <td>
```

(...)

$album contains and displays the data, but $jsonalbum is empty! And i cant find whats wrong..
any help?
thank you!

pablo

Comment: I can suggest you to try json_encode instead of Zend_Json::encode to see if its an issue with your $albums array or issue with Zend_Json.

Comment: print_r of $album prints: Zend_Db_Table_Row Object ( [_data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [artist] => Paolo Nutine [title] => Sunny Side Up [tstamp] => 2012-02-04 21:16:44 [user] => [place] => [description] => ) (...) and print_r of $jsonalbum prints: {} {} {} {} {} with both (Zend_jason::enconde and json_encode)

Comment: got it. i had to transform the row object to an array first! as taken from here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.row.html example 4. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, the attributes of your album are protected and according to Zend_Json documentation, Zend_Json::encode() can access only public attributes.

> If you are encoding PHP objects by default the encoding mechanism can only access public properties of these objects. When a method toJson() is implemented on an object to encode, Zend_Json calls this method and expects the object to return a JSON representation of its internal state.

[Zend_Json Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.advanced.html)

Implement method toJson() in your album to be able to turn it into json

Answer (score 1):

try casting it to an array : `$jsonalbum =  Zend_Json::encode((array) $album);`

Answer (score 0):

> JSON does not allow object references, so care should be taken not to encode objects with recursive references. If you have issues with recursion, Zend_Json::encode() and Zend_Json_Encoder::encode() allow an optional second parameter to check for recursion; if an object is serialized twice, an exception will be thrown.

maybe fault in this?